# CSS Button styling not working

Tags: css, html, button

Heads up: I am new to this forum and English is not my main language so sorry if its not completely understandable.

I am making a mobile website for school and it is going pretty far so well...

One problem: i have a thingy(sorry, dont know the name for it) in my css file(#styled_button) and works fine. There is one button i wanted to be positioned differently so i copied the code from '#styled_button' and created a new thingy and added postion:relative; and float:right; but for some reason my button doesnt get styled at all now. (i did change the id on my button).

EDIT: If i change my button id back to button_styled it is styled.

Even without changing the code, so #logout_button is the same as #button_styled, nothing happens.

My button:

```
<form action='m.member.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' name='logout_button' value='Logout' id="button_styled">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#button_styled {
    color:white;
    background:#666;
    font: bold 45px Harabara;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

EDIT: Typo removed(wasnt copy pasted from my original code), but the problem is not with the form since it works...

As by request of 'brbcode' here is the code of one of the other buttons im using:

```
<form action='m.loginscreen.php' method='POST'>
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type='text' name='username' id="styled">
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type='password' name='password' id="styled"><br>
    <ul>
        <li><input type='submit' name="loginbutton" value='Log In'            class="button_styled"></li>
        <li><input type='submit' name="registerbutton" value='Register' class="button_styled"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

PS: Sorry again for my fluency in english, but for those that didnt fully understand my button works its just the styling...

Comment: Not sure why it was tagged under PHP

Comment: @DeepakKamat, there is no "elements" in CSS :)

Comment: `<from action="..">` should be `form`. Also, can you give us an example of the other button you are trying to use?

Comment: @MiljanPuzović ohh yeah! It must be Selector then :D

Comment: you should also consider using `<button>` instead of `<input>`. safe back to like IE5.5, it allows additional styling (images, more text options, etc), and if you set the `type="submit"` it'll operate the exact same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using an ID on several elements in your html(?). ID's should only be used once per page - typically if you have one element that's different than all others. If you're using the `button_styled` type in several places, you should change it to a **class**. In your html:

```
<input class="button_styled" ... >
```

And in your CSS:

```
.button_styled {
  /* your styling */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now, still cant understand how the use of an id interferes with another id since there is no relation between them but thank u so much. <3(no homo)

Comment: @iDobbler it's because you can use an id once only, while a class, unlimited times. I believe.